# Django GenericForiegnKey, specify ContentTypes include/exclude for admin

Tags: python, django, django-contenttypes

If I have a GenericForeignKey

```
class Prereq(models.Model):
    target_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='prereq_parent')
    target_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    target_object = GenericForeignKey("target_content_type", "target_object_id")
```

How can I create an include or exclude list for which models/ContentTypes I want included in the admin form?

Currently, I get a list of about 30 models (all the models in the project), when really I only want about 3 or 4 of those models

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide custom `ModelForm` on your admin and limit queryset inside `target_content_type` field.

```
class PrereqAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PrereqAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['target_content_type'].queryset = ContentType.objects.filter(your_conditions='something')

class PrereqAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PrereqAdminForm
```

Also you can add `limit_choices_to` directly into your `target_content_type` field in `Prereq` class:

```
class Prereq(models.Model):
    target_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='prereq_parent', limit_choices_to=conditions)
    target_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    target_object = GenericForeignKey("target_content_type", "target_object_id")
```

Where conditions can be an dictionary, `Q` object (like in filter) or some callable returning dictionary or `Q` object.

Comment: Thanks! Followup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298527/filter-a-django-contenttype-queryset-to-only-include-models-that-have-a-specific

Comment: Accepted too soon, sorry! customizing the model form is giving me this error: `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` on this line `   `self.fields['target_content_type'].queryset = ContentType.objects.all()`. using .all() for now until I can get it working, then will add filter()

Comment: Did you call `__init__` from super before trying to change queryset?

Comment: Yes, `def __init__()` it looks just like your example, however, the form I am working on is not a `ModelForm` but a `GenericTabularInline`.  Is that the problem?

Comment: I think I should ask this as a new question as it wasn't part of the original.

Comment: Inline and Form are 2 different things, but Inline operates on form. Just create separate form, like in my example and pass it class into form attribute of that inline.

Comment: Just like in example, but instead of having ModelAdmin, you will have your inline class.