# Filter a DJango ContentType queryset to only include models that have a specific method

Tags: python, django, django-contenttypes

How can I filter a `ContentType` queryset to only include models that have a specific method?

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def mySpecificMethod:
        ...
```

What can I put in `???` to get all models where `mySpecificMethod` exists?

```
ContentType.objects.filter(???)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is more proper to filter it by loop.

If you intend to get a result of type `QuerySet`, you can simply loop them, then get the ID list, then use `pk__in` parameter to filter it.

```
ContentType.objecst.filter(
    pk__in=[
        ct.pk for ct ContentType.objects.all() 
        if content_type_has_method(ct, 'method_name')
    ]
)
```

So, you have reduced this question to write a method:

```
def content_type_has_method(ct, method_name):
    ...
```

And I think that is simpler for you, good luck!

Comment: That is magical!  I think the `for` loop just needs an `in`:
`ct.pk for ct in  ContentType.objects.all()`